# i can't start avd emulator (android studio) or test in my device

Tags: android, flutter

i use flutter to make some projects and i want to test them ,from several days i tried to test them as usual with the AVD but it didn't start (when i start avd nothing happened).so i told my self to test it with my device and the same problem
and i get error (not in code) and i solve it
i have uninstall android studio and delete the sdk then reinstall it again  nothing changed
i tried to use other IDE like vs code but it have same problem
i delete flutter SDK too and reinstall it but noting changed
i have windows 10

Comment: is that away to run as android without avd (android studio emulator)? i mean is there other emulator ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to start your AVD device with the cold boot option?
You can also try to create a new AVD device and see if that one boots up.

Comment: i removed my AVD device ,created new one and the same problem